# Opengl superbible example compliation errors Source code: drawing a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to OpenGL and I'm now trying examples in the book, I've included all the libraries and headers correctly, but it seems there are still something not going right.

These are headers that I included :

[image]  [image] [image]

This is the code :

```
// Triangle.cpp
// Our first OpenGL program that will just draw a triangle on the screen.
#include <GLTools.h> // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h> // Shader Manager Class
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h> // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h> // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif
GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context.
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
{
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();
    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();
    // Perform the buffer swap to display the back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow(“Triangle”);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, “GLEW Error: %s\n”, glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Error messsages given :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: openglproj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Triangle.cpp
1>d:\xing bizhou\project\openglproj\triangle.cpp(57) : error C2065: '“Triangle”' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\xing bizhou\project\openglproj\triangle.cpp(62) : error C2065: '“GLEW' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\xing bizhou\project\openglproj\triangle.cpp(62) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'Error'
1>d:\xing bizhou\project\openglproj\triangle.cpp(62) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>d:\xing bizhou\project\openglproj\triangle.cpp(62) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\XING BIZHOU\project\openglproj\openglproj\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>openglproj - 5 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: My graphic card is: Intel HD3000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using "pretty quotes" in your code.

C++ expects a **specific character** `"` to be used as a *double quote*.  It may not be replaced with similar-looking characters.

Change:

`“Triangle”` and `“GLEW Error: %s\n”`

To:

`"Triangle"` and `"GLEW Error: %s\n"`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there appears a new error message :1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut_staticd.lib', but I have alreay add it in the project

Comment: If this answered your posted question, please mark it as accepted.  If you have a new question, you are free to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)